# Verifying the Divergence Theorem for Half of a Sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Here is an exercise that I was assigned for homework:

[image: Homework Problem]
..........................................................

To the bottom left, I have scanned an example problem for verifying the divergence theorem that my professor presented in lecture. To the bottom right, I have scanned my attempt at completing the homework problem.

[image: My work]
..........................................................

So basically, I did not get the correct value for either integral, and the integrals did not match either. I don't think I've made any basic calculation errors, so I suspect that I'm messing up somewhere conceptually.

Here are some specific things that I have questions for clarification on: (1) Is $\nabla \cdot F(\phi (\theta, \psi))$ the dot product of $\nabla$ and $F(\phi (\theta, \psi))$? (2) Is my parametrization of the hemisphere correct? (3) How do I tell if my normal is outward? (4) This isn't a question, but obviously I didn't use the $t=cos\theta $ substitution that my professor says is needed.

If there is an intuitive solution to this problem, I'd be happy to hear it, but I would mainly like to know how to do it step-by-step.

Thanks!

Comment: You know LaTex, right? It is easier for many to read LaTex instead of handwritten images. Could you please put your question's images into LaTex format?

Comment: One problem is that in your volume integral you did not integrate over a volume but over nothing really. You need to take the radial direction into consideration. That will fix the first integral

Comment: In the second integral, you made some sort of algebra mistake when computing the cross product. A two popped up when it should not have. Look at your "z" term in the cross product. Then this integral will be correct however you will not be done yet. The divergence theorem applies to closed surfaces. So you will need to compute the surface integral over the bottom of the hemisphere, I.e. a circle at z=0.  I'm not on a computer so maybe someone can write out a more complete answer if this isn't enough.